# Como ocultar o horário de um campo "DateTime?" na interface do usuário?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

O horário esta aparecendo para o usuário.

Minha dúvida: é possivel ocultar o horário e mostrar apenas a data?

Como está aparacendo:
[image: interface]

Código do model:

[image: model]

Código da view:

[image: view]

Comment: Se possível coloque o código fonte ao inves de uma imagem dele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar o método `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` utilize o `.ToShortDateString()`, pois ele fará a conversão para string desconsiderando a hora, porém o mais legal é que ele irá seguir as regras definidas nas `CultureInfo` do seu aplicativo. Ou seja, se estiver em português (pt-BR) será `dd/MM/yyyy`, mas se estiver em inglês (en-US) será `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```
item.DataInicial.ToShortDateString() // somente a data (como solicitou)
item.DataInicial.ToShortTimeString() // somente a hora
```

Se o seu campo for `DateTime`? (nullable), você vai precisar pegar o valor através do `Value`.

```
if(item.DateInicial.HasValue){ item.DateInicial.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
```

Existem muitos outros métodos na classe `DateTime`.

Comment: Perfeito.. funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta utilizar o Format do String, exemplo `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`, no caso:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.DataInicial.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "Index", new { apuracaoSelecionada = item.ApuracaoIcmsID })
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou, como o campo é "DateTime?" precisei colocar (item.DataFinal.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") o "Value" tbm, obrigado.

Comment: Verdade! Tinha me esquecido do `Nullable`, corrigido no exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Como você está exibindo manualmente a data, fazendo ToString(), basta você especificar um formatador:

```
item.DataInicial.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

[Documentação da MSDN sobre o método ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Opa, funcionou, como o campo é "DateTime?" precisei colocar (item.DataFinal.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") o "Value" tbm, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Substitua a variável `DateTime` por uma variável `Date`